# How to load another controller throughout all the controllers in ZF project?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a code snippet that checks user logins and gets navigations and etc throughout the whole site. I have a few controllers and I want that snippet to be in all of them. I get tired  of changing all of them one at a time whenever I change something. In one of my other projects I saw it somehow extended to the other controllers using this portion

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

and it looked like

```
class MyController extends MySnippet_Controller_Action
```

or something of that sort, and it worked. I however can't get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is likely a frontcontroller plugin registered against init() or more likely predispatch(). In Zend Framework extending Zend_Controller_Action is frowned upon and in truth is not usually required.

these resources may help you develope the plugin(s) you need:

[Understand ZF plugins pt 1](http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2012/07/understanding-zend-frameworks-plugin.html)
[Understand ZF plugins pt 2](http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2012/08/understanding-zend-frameworks-plugin.html)

[and of course the reference manual section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

Here is the basic form of a plugin:

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_Acl extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        parent::preDispatch($request);
        //truncated
    }
}
```

Comment: So I would create the plugin, put in a folder somewhere like /lib (not in controllers, models?) Then tell bootstrap to run the processes I want? I don't have to edit my controllers or init() or anything? In other words, how would my controllers look and where would I put this plugin class?

Comment: Reading this article http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/zend/simple-controller-plugin-in-zend-framework/ It says I create the plugin folder, so I can create a folder next to my controllers, models, views called plugins? and put it there, and then load it in bootstrap from there and it should be good?

Comment: typically you would put the pluging in `application/library/yourNamespace` or anywhere else you want. You would then register the plugin in your application.ini with one line `resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "My_Controller_Plugin_Acl"` or you could register the plugin in your bootstrap.